# Enable Custom Elements in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, web-component

How can I enable Custom Elements in Firefox 31/32?  According to [Are We Componentized yet?](http://jonrimmer.github.io/are-we-componentized-yet/#fnDecorators) there is "in progress support" but I can't see it, and googling was unhelpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After some experimentation, it appears that the way to use the in-progress Web Components support in firefox is by navigating to `about:config` in firefox and enabling the `dom.webcomponents.enabled` flag.  In Firefox 31 that seems to (at minimum) enable implementations of `document.registerElement` and the various custom element lifecycle callbacks.

Comment: Can we do it programmatically?

Comment: @BrendaOliviaMartis No idea when you commented this, but not anymore. Even back then (FF 31) you could only do it via an add-on, and I don't think the current (57+) WebExtensions framework provides access to prefs.js settings.