# Polymer looks different on firefox and chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, polymer

im new to polymer just want to know why it looks different from chrome and fox?

chrome looks good but in fox it looks different like the color of the scaffold toolbar, logo and content, im using firefox 33.1

**url:** http://jigs-gfx.net/polymer/practice/

Comment: already fixed it by adding style or importing css inside my element

Answer (score 0):

Firefox doesn't seem to be honoring your use of the deep shadow elements in your site.css file.

```
header-koh::shadow .logo{
```

Is valid in chrome, but not in Firefox. Firefox doesn't fully support web components and all their conventions out of the box, but you can enable the dom.webcomponents.enabled flag to turn them on and get a similar experience across browsers. A guide to how to enable the feature is given here:

[Enable Custom Elements in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25220821/enable-custom-elements-in-firefox)

Firefox and IE both have full web component support in progress and hopefully will support them out of the box soon.

Comment: Just as a random comment: Firefox and Polymer does not work properly, regardless of the "polyfill". CSS is the problem, its not encapsulated good enough, so it tends to screw up in FF. That means, for me, that this project is dead until it works as flawless in FF as it does in Chrome.