# How to get custom elements working in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

I have this basic custom element example. It is working in Chrome, however not in Firefox. Is there a way to get it working in Firefox (without polymer but maybe some kind of polyfill)?

I also enabled the `dom.webcomponents.enabled` flag without any success.

---

### Update:

Since this is solved, I created a repository, with the complete code:
https://github.com/peplow/webcomponent-example/

---

Custom element html file:

```
<template id="template">
  <button id="button">Hallo</button>
  <style media="screen">
    button{
      color:red;
    }
  </style>
</template>

<script>
    var localDoc = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;
    class toggleButton extends HTMLElement{

      constructor(){
        super();
        this.shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
        var template = localDoc.querySelector('#template');
        this.shadow.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));

        this.shadow.querySelector('button').onclick = function(){
          alert("Hello World");
        }
      }

      static get observedAttributes() {return ['name']; }

      attributeChangedCallback(attr, oldValue, newValue) {
        if (attr == 'name') {
          this.shadow.querySelector('#button').innerHTML = newValue;
        }
      }

    }

    customElements.define('x-toggle', toggleButton);
</script>
```

File where it is used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="import" href="element.html">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <x-toggle name="Hello World"></x-toggle>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable Custom Elements in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25220821/enable-custom-elements-in-firefox)

Comment: I enabled the flag but it seems like it changed nothing

Comment: There's any error on js console when you execute it on Firefox?

Comment: No, it's clear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firefox has not yet shipped Custom Elements v1, which is the latest standard and is what specifies `customElements.define()` as the way to define an element (as opposed to v0 which used `document.registerElement()` and is what is available with the `dom.webcomponents.enabled` flag in Firefox).

Chrome is currently the only browser that supports Custom Elements v1 natively, but all other major browsers are supportive of it.

Firefox has [an open bug for Custom Elements v1 support](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=889230).

In the meantime, your best bet is to use the [Custom Elements v1 Polyfill](https://github.com/webcomponents/custom-elements) for browsers that don't support it. You can feature-detect Custom Elements v1 support with `'customElements' in window`.

Comment: Somehow it didn't worked by loading webcomponents.js however it worked by loading `webcomponents-lite.js`, `custom-elements.js`, `shadydom.js`, and `shadycss.js` separately. Thank you!

Comment: Opera also supports CustomElements FYI

Comment: Safari 10.1 added Custom Elements v1 support as well

Answer (score 13):

As of June 2018, Firefox support for Custom Elements can be enabled with the following steps

1. Type in the search bar `about:config`.
2. search for `dom.webcomponents.shadowdom.enabled` click to enable.
3. serch for `dom.webcomponents.customelements.enabled` click to enable.

Hope this helps someone out there.

**UPDATE**: 
Now, since Firefox 63, Custom Elements are supported in Firefox by default.

Comment: So if the user of FF wants to open a site that uses custom elements, HE NEEDS to enable them by these commands?

Comment: That was the case in older versions of Firefox, however now since Firefox 63, its supported by default.