# window.customElements is undeifned in older firefox browser

Tags: javascript

I have a firefox version 60.* and my machine is throwing the

> "window.customElements is undefined"

Here is my part of code

```
 window.customElements.define('test-piechart',
        class extends HTMLElement {
          constructor() {
            super();

          }

         connectedCallback() {
          }
    });
```

Based on the reaserch and I found that window.customElements not supported in < firfox 63.* and supported by default since firefox version  > 63.*.  I knew we can get it worked dom.webcomponents.customelements.enabled even in old firefox < 63.* 
But what is an alternative solution to work even in older versions of browsers as well as later versions also wihtout these settings.
I understood from another post that it can be achieved using the Polyfill, but any code snippet using ployfill how that can be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get custom elements working in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40677265/how-to-get-custom-elements-working-in-firefox) - The accepted answer suggests using [this polyfill](https://github.com/webcomponents/custom-elements).

Comment: The specified post has well explained the reasons for problem and specified using the polyfill. But it does not contain how that can be achieved using the polyfill.